# How to change Height of UISegmentedControl's divider

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm using UISegmentedControl in my project and I need to change height of divider which is in UISegmentedControl.

How Can Do that ?

First of all I know we can change divider's color like that.

```
self.setDividerImage(selectedBorderImage, forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
```

But I need to change height of divider.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's possible by writing its custom. First, you need to pass a **UIImage()** empty to the divider

```
self.setDividerImage(UIImage(), forLeftSegmentState: .normal, rightSegmentState: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
```

then you create a view for the **separator**, give it a size,  and add it as subview of **segmentControl**. To calculate the position of separator you need to do it when the layout is already laid.

```
          var constant: CGFloat = 0
          guard let first = self.subviews.first else { return }
          #warning("Implementation Custom can be deprecated in the years")
          if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            constant = first.frame.width
          } else {
            constant = first.frame.minX
          }
          separator?.removeFromSuperview()
          separator = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: constant, y: 5, width: 1, height: 30))
          separator?.backgroundColor = .black
          self.addSubview(separator.unsafelyUnwrapped)
      }
```